# How can I rename files recursively using a regular expression

Tags: regular-expression, filenames, rename, recursive

I have hundreds of files on a hard drive with many directories and sub directories which start with:

`1.1`, `1.2`, `1.3`, `2.1`, `3.1`, `9.1`, `10.1`, `10.2`, Etc Etc...

The problem is that when I list them they appear like this:
`10.1`, `10.2`, `1.1`, `1.2`, and so on.

The zero comes before the period, so I need to rename all files which start this way by swapping the period between two digits for a hyphen so as to list them:
`1-1`, `2-1`, `9-1`, `10-1`, `11-1` etc.

I used to name my music and video filenames `01-01.ext`, `01-02.ext`, `01-10.ext`, `02-01.ext`
This worked great, I had a senior moment when I named hundreds of files with a period :|

I have tried to find the answer to this but they are either not what I need, or too baffling for me to understand...

I'm using Linux Mint 20.3 Una. I have tried going to the root of my hard drive (a test one with some dummy files!!) in terminal and trying various combinations like:
`'s,^[0-9]\.[0-9]*',[0-9]\-[0-9]*.*` But this is all trial and error stuff (and it sure does error!) I don't know anywhere near enough to work this out myself.

I'm sure this would have been answered somewhere, I just can't find where!

**1st off, thank you for your tips.**

If I am viewing DVD programmes on devices other than my Linux PC, they might be listed in order, but maybe not. So, ideally, I would like to change the file names, everywhere on my hard drive.  Here is a typical list of such...

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 222647532 Jun  4  2010 5.9 Mr Chairman.mp4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 229849021 Jun  5  2010 6.10 Well Well Well.mp4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 236174416 Jun  5  2010 6.11 The Phantom Pools Winner.mp4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 242440279 Jun  5  2010 6.12 A Matter Of Principle.mp4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 229969047 Jun  5  2010 6.13 Some Enchanted Evening.mp4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 244241841 Jun  4  2010 6.1 The Frozen Limit.mp4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 239823201 Jun  4  2010 6.2 Beautiful Dreamer.mp4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 231566965 Jun  4  2010 6.3 Fish With Everything.mp4
```

Something like this is probably what I'm looking for.

```
rename -n 's/\./-/' *
```

But I have to get the period(s) between numbers as the file names will contain periods themselves, if only the extension, i.e.: `02.01.05 Mr. Baz.mp4`.

My original question was as clear as mud... Hopefully this is a bit clearer.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. It's a bit difficult to understand your requirements here. Please use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format your file names as code and show us the actual names. Ideally, the output of `ls` in one of the relevant directories. Then also explain how we can know what names to change. Where does the `1-1` come from, for example? Is that the old `1.1`? And is that the entire file name? Are they all numbers and `.`?

Comment: Maybe you want to use `ls -V` and `set -o numericglobsort` (if using `zsh` as your shell) to sort file names numerically.

Comment: Wait, are you just looking for `rename -n 's/\./-/' *`? Run this in the top level dir which contains all the files/dirs you want to rename and tell us if that looks like what you want. Don't worry, as long as you use the `-n`, that won't actually rename any files, it will only show what it would rename were you to run it without the `-n`.

Comment: I doubt replacing `.` with `-` will make much difference. But it usually works pretty well if the numbers are zero-padded.

Answer (score 0):

Not really answering the how-to of the question but looking beyond that to the reason, on systems with GNU `ls` you can use `ls -v` to list the files in "natural" order. Here's what the documentation (`man ls`) has to say,

> `-v` natural sort of (version) numbers within text

And here's the example,

```
mkdir /tmp/737361
cd /tmp/737361
touch 1.1 1.2 1.3 2.1 3.1 9.1 10.1 10.2
```

First,

```
ls
1.1  1.2  1.3  10.1  10.2  2.1  3.1  9.1
```

But,

```
ls -v
1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  3.1  9.1  10.1  10.2
```